# Function not being defined while called in another function (Python)

Tags: python, function

I am writing an algo for a project (I'm sure I have errors elsewhere in my code, but don't help me there as I will work through those later).  But I am running into basic python organization errors.  Basically I'm using a library (networkX) and have a graph which is fully functional (I have tested it already, nodes and edges). I am running into errors on how to set my parameters and then to actually execute the ham_main() function.

```
def ham_walk(self, graph, path):
    if len(path) == len(graph.nodes()):
        return True
    for neighbor in graph.neighbors(path.pop()):
        if neighbor not in path:
            ham_walk(graph, path.append(neighbor))
    return False

def ham_main(self):
    graph = self.getGraph()
    print(graph.nodes())
    print(graph.edges())
    path = []
    for node in graph.nodes():
        path = [node]
        if ham_walk(self, graph, path):
            return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
        else:
            print("False")
            return False
    return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
  class Main:
      execute = HamParser()
      execute.ham_main()
```

When I try to execute in my main class I get the following error ;

```
      File "C:/Users/Chris/Dropbox/HamProgram.py", line 33, in ham_main
       if ham_walk(self, graph, path):
       NameError: name 'ham_walk' is not defined
```

It seems as though ham_walk is not registering.  Am I missing something vital here?

EDIT: Full Code

```
from sys import argv
import networkx as nx


class HamParser:

    def getGraph(self):
        adjLines = []
        test = "input001.txt"
        with open(test, 'r') as adjFile:
        #with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as adjFile:
            adjFile.readline()
            for line in adjFile:
                adjLines.append(line.strip())
        G = nx.parse_adjlist(adjLines, nodetype=int)
        return G

    def ham_walk(self, graph, path):
        if len(path) == len(graph.nodes()):
            return True
        for neighbor in graph.neighbors(path.pop()):
            if neighbor not in path:
                ham_walk(graph, path.append(neighbor))
        return False

    def ham_main(self):
        graph = self.getGraph()
        print(graph.nodes())
        print(graph.edges())
        path = []
        for node in graph.nodes():
            path = [node]
            if ham_walk(self, graph, path):
                return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
            else:
                print("False")
                return False
        return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)


class Main:
    execute = HamParser()
    execute.ham_main()
```

Comment: show the full code ??

Comment: What is the `Main` class for?

Comment: change `ham_walk(self, graph, path)` to `self.ham_walk(graph, path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
from sys import argv
import networkx as nx


class HamParser:

    def getGraph(self):
        adjLines = []
        test = "input001.txt"
        with open(test, 'r') as adjFile:
        #with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as adjFile:
            adjFile.readline()
            for line in adjFile:
                adjLines.append(line.strip())
        G = nx.parse_adjlist(adjLines, nodetype=int)
        return G

    def ham_walk(self, graph, path):
        if len(path) == len(graph.nodes()):
            return True
        for neighbor in graph.neighbors(path.pop()):
            if neighbor not in path:
                self.ham_walk(graph, path.append(neighbor))
        return False

    def ham_main(self):
        graph = self.getGraph()
        print(graph.nodes())
        print(graph.edges())
        path = []
        for node in graph.nodes():
            path = [node]
            if self.ham_walk(self, graph, path):
                return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
            else:
                print("False")
                return False
        return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)


class Main:
    execute = HamParser()
    execute.ham_main()
```

Comment: Yep, this worked.  Thank you I know this wasn't the most structured question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
if ham_walk(self, graph, path):
```

You don't need to pass self in as a parameter, the definition of `ham_walk`
knows which object instance to reference.  Just change it to:

```
if self.ham_walk(graph, path):
```

Comment: Again yea this fixed it.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

from sys import argv
import networkx as nx

class HamParser:

```
def getGraph(self):
    adjLines = []
    test = "input001.txt"
    with open(test, 'r') as adjFile:
    #with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as adjFile:
        adjFile.readline()
        for line in adjFile:
            adjLines.append(line.strip())
    G = nx.parse_adjlist(adjLines, nodetype=int)
    return G

def ham_walk(self, graph, path):
    if len(path) == len(graph.nodes()):
        return True
    for neighbor in graph.neighbors(path.pop()):
        if neighbor not in path:
            self.ham_walk(graph, path.append(neighbor))
    return False

def ham_main(self):
    graph = self.getGraph()
    print(graph.nodes())
    print(graph.edges())
    path = []
    for node in graph.nodes():
        path = [node]
        if self.ham_walk(graph, path):
        # NOT if self.ham_walk(self, graph, path):
        # self is bound as first arg when HamPath() is instantiated.
        #     by putting self in the call again, you are basically passing self in a second time, and calling ham_walk with a second "self" where graph should be. 
        #  in this case, it will throw error b/c number of args (3) does not match signature (2)
            return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
        else:
            print("False")
            return False
    return print("Hamiltonian Path: " + path)
```

class Main:
    execute = HamParser()
    execute.ham_main()